# Backwards JavaScript less-than logic....sometimes

Tags: javascript, logic

My code couldn't be simpler...

```
if (iWant > thereAre){
    msg = "There's only "+thereAre+" left, but you want "+iWant
} else {
    gimmie
}
```

But sometimes it works.. sometimes it does the else{ every time... sometimes the if{ every time... I will switch the > to a < and then it will still function as before....?

Can JS be broken?
I'm ending up with messages that say "*There's only 87 left, but you want 2*"... sometimes...sometimes it works great.

The **iWant** var is getting pulled from a form post

The **thereAre** var is getting pulled from a MySql COUNT

Please help.. I feel like I'm going crazy.

Comment: Are you parsing the strings to numbers ? `"33"<"4"` is true.

Comment: You are looking for <= as in `if (iWant <= thereAre) gimme();
  else  msg = "There's only "+thereAre+" left, but you want "+iWant`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes a variable may be a number 4 or the string '4'.

If you want number comparison, not string comparison, then you can multiply by 1 or use parseInt/parseFloat to guarantee that you are dealing with numbers.

```
if (1*iWant > 1*thereAre ){ 
  too much; 
} else {
  ok;
}
```

However, if user input somehow becomes involved and iWant is "two" or "2oops" instead of 2 or "2", this code will still function but not in a useful way.

Optionally you might want to detect non-numbers if it is an issue.

Comment: You can do it in a single character with the unary `+` operator, i.e., `+"33" == 33`

Comment: Good to know.  But + is overloaded, though, and that's why I like 1*

Comment: @apsillers Thank you for making me aware of this.  I tested this in nodeJS and you are correct.  I'll change the answer to delete the try/catch.

Comment: I was using cleanInt() to accomplish pretty much this.. apparently it does not. This solution appears to do the trick. If it's still working all day I'll mark this as the answer. THANKS!!!!!